# jquery Clic on radio button and border a TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

As the picture attached, I have a simple HTML table with radio button within each cell. I need to outline a cell once the usr clicks on the cell's radio button.

```
<table class='TablaBlanca' border= '0'>
<tr id='V14_1'>
<td><label for='Input_V14_1'><input id ='Input_V14_1' type='radio' name='V14' value='1'     class='validateCallback'><img src='instructivo_1.png'></label></td>
</tr>

<tr id='V14_2'>
<td><label for='Input_V14_2'><input id ='Input_V14_2' type='radio' name='V14' value='2'    class='validateCallback'><img src='ThumpUp.jpg'></label></td>
</tr>

<tr id='V14_3'>
<td><label for='Input_V14_3'><input id ='Input_V14_3' type='radio' name='V14' value='3' class='validateCallback'><img src='wfi_on.jpg'></label></td>
</tr>

<tr id='V14_4'>
<td><label for='Input_V14_4'><input id ='Input_V14_4' type='radio' name='V14' value='4' class='validateCallback'><img src='instructivo_1.jpg'></label></td>
</tr>

<tr id='V14_5'>
<td><label for='Input_V14_5'><input id ='Input_V14_5' type='radio' name='V14' value='5'   class='validateCallback'><img src='instructivo_3.jpg'></label></td>
</tr>
```

This code works fine, but all the row is outlined, however I need to outline just a single cell.

```
$('input:radio[name="V14"]').click(function(){
    $('input:radio[name="V14"]').parent().css({ border:'' });
    $('input:radio[name="V14"]:checked').parent().css({ border:'4px solid black' });
});
```

Any idea?, this is logical, but it does not work:

```
    $('input:radio[name="V14"]').css({ border:'' });
    $('input:radio[name="V14"]:checked').css({ border:'4px solid black' });
```

Here is a JSFiddle to try: http://jsfiddle.net/PjL6v/

Thanks

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: I did: http://jsfiddle.net/PjL6v/

Answer (score 1):

You can't give a border to a radio button element: [see here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953) on how to style such elements.

In short, style the radio's label:

```
$('input:radio[name="V14"] + label').css({ border:'' });
$('input:radio[name="V14"]:checked + label').css({ border:'4px solid black' });
```

*Notice the `+ label` selector?*

Or, style the cell using [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
$('input:radio[name="V14"]').parent().css({ border:'' });
$('input:radio[name="V14"]:checked').parent().css({ border:'4px solid black' });
```

Comment: Sir, the border is requiered for the TD, the radio is within the TD

Comment: Sure, and the above code sets its parent element, `td`, to have a 4px solid black border?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "outline single cell." Right now your code is highlighting the parent of the input element, which is the label. If you want to highlight the cell itself, i.e., the td, you'd do this:

```
$('input:radio[name="V14"]:checked').closest('td').css({ 
    border:'4px solid black' 
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wg49x/

Comment: Sir, a cell is just a TD, like this <td> cell </td>, in your jsfiddle sample you point out to a parent, but a parent is  tr, I dont need the whole row (tr) outlined, just the cell

Comment: Updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wg49x/2/ -- this code changes the td that contains a checked radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$('input:radio[name="V14"]').click(function(){
$(this).parent().css({ border:'' });
// the rest of code
});
```

When you say `input:radio[name="V14` click, you must do your manipulations on the element which has been clicked. not all the elements matched. So use `$(this)` in your `click` function.

Comment: Have you replaced all `input:radio[name="V14"]` inside your click function with `this` ?